# Can someone explain this coding challenge for me?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I stumbled upon a following coding exercise online:

> "Here is a Japanese abacus which you can use for calculations in the
> decimal system. Successive digits in the decimal system are
> represented by successive columns of the abacus, starting from the
> right. In the upper row one bead has a value of 5, in each of the
> lower rows - a value of 1. You have some number of beads and your task
> is to allocate them between lower rows (max. four beads in one column)
> in order to maximize the number of values that can be represented on
> the abacus. You may assume, that there are all beads in the upper
> row." Help Johnny find a solution to his problem!
>
> Input Every data set consists of two positive integers r s given in
> one row, where 1 <= r <= 8 represents the number of columns in abacus
> and 0 <= s <= 4 * r is the number of beads that Johnny has to
> distribute between columns in the lower rows.
>
> Output Write to output the maximum number of correct values that can
> be represented on such broken Soroban.
>
> Example 1 Input: 21
>
> Output: 8
>
> Example 2 Input: 23
>
> Output: 24

Can someone explain to me the example outputs given in the exercise? I don't understand why for input "21" the correct answer is 8. I can think of more than 8 valid numbers generated my an soroban with 2 columns and one bead in the bottom, like:

```
+-----------------------------+---------------+---------------------------+---------------+
| d|d                         | d|d           | d|u                       | d|u           |
| -|-   value 55              | -|-  value 56 | -|-  value 50             | -|-  value 51 |
|  |d                         |  |u           |  |d                       |  |u           |
+-----------------------------+---------------+---------------------------+---------------+
| u|d                         | u|d           | u|u                       | u|u           |
| -|-  value 5                | -|-  value 6  | -|-  value 0              | -|-  value 1  |
|  |d                         |  |u           |  |d                       |  |u           |
+-----------------------------+---------------+---------------------------+---------------+
| d|d                         | d|d           | d|u                       | d|u           |
| -|-   value 55 (duplicate)  | -|-  value 65 | -|-  value 50 (duplicate) | -|-  value 60 |
| d|                          | u|            | d|                        | u|            |
+-----------------------------+---------------+---------------------------+---------------+
| u|d                         | u|d           | u|u                       | u|u           |
| -|-  value 5 (duplicate)    | -|-  value 16 | -|-  value 0 (duplicate)  | -|-  value 10 |
| d|                          | u|            | d|                        | u|            |
+-----------------------------+---------------+---------------------------+---------------+
```

So here, I see 12 correct numbers that can be generated from Example 1 data. Why would the correct answer be 8? What am I missing? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You misunderstand the premise. You need to distribute the beads between the columns in all possible ways, find the number of representable integers for each distribution separately, and pick the maximum. You are not supposed to find how many numbers are representable with all distributions combined.

Comment: ohhh that makes much more sense, thanks!